# Animating UILabel element with CoreAnimation in Swift

Tags: ios, core-animation, swift

I'm learning how to use CoreAnimation with various UI elements. Ultimately I would like to perform complex, queued animations on all ui elements on screen as I transition to the next view.

Now however I am attempting something really simple. I want to transform (scale up) a UILabel on button tap.

I have the following function:

```
func animateUIElementsOut(element : AnyObject) {

  var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform");

  var transform : CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 1);

  animation.setValue(NSValue(CATransform3D: transform), forKey: "scaleText");

  animation.duration = 2.0;

  element.layer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "scaleText");

}
```

I am calling the function on a button tap like this:

```
  animateUIElementsOut(greetingsLabel);
```

The compiler isn't giving off any warnings, however the animation is  not working. What am I doing wrong here?

As per @David Rönnqvist suggestions the working code looks like this (fromValue / toValue added):

```
func animateUIElementsOut(element : AnyObject) {

  var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform");

  animation.delegate = self;

  var transform : CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 1);

  animation.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity);
  animation.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: transform);

  animation.duration = 2.0;

  element.layer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation doesn't have neither a `toValue` or a `fromValue`.

You are setting the transform for the `"scaleText"` key on the animation but the animation doesn't have a corresponding property.

To make the *animation* itself work you should set the transform as the `toValue` of the animation. However, there are still things missing to make the whole thing work. The model value of the layer is never changed so when the animation finished and is removed, you will see the old (model) values again.

If you are only interested in making a scaling animation, I would recommend that you use the higher level UIView animation APIs instead:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) {
    element.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)
}
```

If on the other hand you are interested in working with Core Animation, there are a couple more things to do to make it all work.

1. configure the animation to go *from* the current model value (using the `fromValue` property)
2. configure the animation to go *to* the new value (as explained above)
3. update the model value to the new value before adding the animation.

---

As a side trivia, the reason that you could set a value for "scaleText" without there being any such property is that layers and animations work a bit differently than most classes with key-value coding. You can set and get any value on both a layer and a view using key-value coding. This means that this is valid code:

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.setValue(1, forKey: "foo")
var foo = layer.valueForKey("foo") // is equal to 1

let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
anim.setValue(2, forKey: "bar")
var bar = anim.valueForKey("bar") // is equal to 2
```

However, if you try and do the same on almost any other object, you will get a runtime exception saying that the class isn't key-value coding compliant for that key. For example, this code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
view.setValue(3, forKey: "baz")
```

Produces this runtime exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x10dc08b30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key baz.'
```

Comment: David thank you for your reply man. These "forKey" / "keyPath" values are certainly tripping me up, so I'll have to read more on those. The good thing is you helped me trigger my animation successfully, so I'll try to build up from there. Once again thanks for taking your time to reply!

Comment: @MartinVelchevski The key path of the animation is what you are animating. The key used when adding the animation is used so that you can reference and manually remove the animation.